# Bootstrap Multiselect - Single select without radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap multi select plugin. Used this plugin for multi select dropdwns and applied the same for single select dropdowns for UI consistency. 
For multiselect dropdowns, I applied as below

```
 $('#ListBox').multiselect({
                nonSelectedText: 'Select Option'
            });
```

It creates, checkboxes in the dropdown and able to select multiple options.

And applied single select dropdown as below,

```
 $('#DropDownList').multiselect({
                nonSelectedText: 'Select Option',
                multiple: false                
            });
```

This one generates radio button in the dropdown but I don't want the radio button and it should be works as normal dropdown.

is there any option to create the single select dropdown without radio button.

Comment: The `multiple: false` indicates you only need single option to be selected.  In that case, you can use a simple HTML combo box.

Comment: Hi Sid,  Yes, You are rite. but I want the UI similar the multiselect dropdown list. That's why I tried like this. Moreover, this should work including in IE 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the below css code and check

```
.dropdown-menu label.radio input[type=radio]{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.dropdown-menu label.radio{
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: So basically you propose to not use multiselect plugin and instead use the regular one?

Comment: For the UI consistency only, I used multiselect plugin for single select one.

Comment: Is there any other way to make the UI as multiselect dropdown?

Comment: @Karthikeyan, Did you try inserting the above css code. I added this on top of multiselect plugin.

Comment: @sameer, Yes, I used the CSS. now UI looks correctly. but not able to choose the dropdown option in IE8

Comment: the problem is only in IE8 not in other versions/browsers. so I just hide the radio button by using above css with little change (padding-left:4px). radio buttons automatically hides now. Thanks sameer

Comment: How to apply this CSS to only several multiselect ?